# What are some names of professional music software for the Macintosh Classic / SE?

Tags: software, mac-os-classic

I'm not asking for opinions, recommendations or reviews.  I'm looking for professional, graphical music creation software for the classic line of Macintosh computers. I'm not looking for *mod* or *tracker* applications.  But applications where you can drag-n-drop musical notes on sheet music.

Please include information such as the names of applications that were produced.

Comment: People have voted to close this question. This could be because answers to this question would largely be lists, and list questions aren't really a good format for the Stack Exchange format (because they can never really be complete). This would cause the question to be too broad. Perhaps you could narrow it down a bit, for example by asking for popular music software, or professional music software, or graphical music software.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 what about questions like http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/fun-or-interesting-projects-to-do-with-mac-classic-ii  that question is purely about suggestions that could go on and on forever.  How is it *ANY* different than mine?  And, BTW, I think said question is on topic...which is why I answered it.

Comment: That question also has votes-to-close on it, and I (personally) would deem it much broader than this one. I think your edit has made the question much less broad; I hope you don't mind if I edit the last paragraph into the main body of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A great one was ConcertWare -- it included composition, playback, and even instrument creation by specifying waveform samples. (It still runs under Mini vMac.)

According to the About box for Version 2.00 from 1985, the program was written by Chad Mitchell, Robert Gardner, and Boyd Edwards, and was published by Great Wave Software.

Here's a typical composition window:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. This is a good answer for the question, but keep in mind that it might not get many upvotes due to the question not being very well received. You might want to have a look at [some other Apple- / Mac-related questions](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii+or+apple-macintosh+or+apple+or+apple-iigs+or+applesoft-basic+or+appletalk+or+apple-lisa+or+apple-dos+or+apple-macintosh+or+mac-os-classic+or+imac-g3+or+imac+or+emac+or+power-macintosh+or+powermac-g5).

Comment: Thanks, @wizzwizz4. I actually think it's a decent question, notwithstanding the close votes. As I recall, there weren't many music creation programs back then, so the OP isn't asking for a giant laundry list.

Comment: @MitchellSpector thanks!  This looks to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @cbmeeks I just saw your edit -- this program does what you asked for, except that the GUI is based on clicking on the note you want, rather than a drag-and-drop operation (drag-and-drop interfaces were not common back then).

Comment: @MitchellSpector actually, that is fine.  I have another application called "Band in a Box" that works with Mac but requires System 7.5 and I think a color display.  What you recommend looks better.

Comment: @cbmeeks Unfortunately I'm not familiar with "Band in a Box", so I can't compare them.